# Leiningen terminates execution of batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, clojure, cmd, leiningen

I'm trying to run the following .bat file using windows CMD:

```
lein run
cd..
```

The first line works perfectly fine and the clojure program does its job:

```
(spit some-file some-stuff)
```

The second line however never gets executed. Why is that?

Comment: What makes you think it didn't?

Comment: If you include more of the .bat file it may help me make an answer that depends less on assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies in advance if I have misunderstood your question. From what I gather it sounds like changing folders within a script sets the new current folder within the script though it does **not necessarily set the current folder from the perspective of the terminal** that invoked the script.

it could make this more clear if you put a print statement after the `cd ..` to show you the directory from the perspective of the script.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
start /b "" lein run
```